# Loading a part of PNG file without reading all of it to stay away from the memory limits

Tags: basic4android

Is there any way of loading a part of PNG file without reading all of it to stay away from the memory limits?

Any solution like Agraham's JPEG Lib that can do same for PNG files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no equivalent library for PNG files. I assume that you are familiar with LoadBitmapSample which can be used to load a scaled down image and avoid out of memory errors.